# How to pass items as references in a PHP's foreach?

Tags: php, parameters, foreach

If I need to change a function parameter, I can use `foo(&$x)` and the function can modify it.
I need something like this in a foreach loop,

```
 $x=array(1,2,3);
 foreach($x as &$i) $i=1;
 var_dump($x);
```

results with some strange "&int(1)"...

```
 array(3) {
   [0]=>
   int(1)
   [1]=>
   int(1)
   [2]=>
   &int(1)
 }
```

But, of course, this is not the syntax (for what I whant)... It is possible to do this with PHP?

---

It is not "so elegant" to use `for` (now it works!),

```
 $x=array(1,2,3);
 for($i=0; $i<count($x); $i++) $x[$i]=1;
 var_dump($x);
```

Comment: [That is precisely the right syntax.](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: As people said, [that is it](http://codepad.org/KnQMvtIo). However, don't forget to `unset($i);` if there is even the slightest change of that variable name being used again in that scope. Or actually, just unset it regardless, best be safe / prevent hard to debug errors.

Comment: The `&int(1)` merely means that there is another reference to that array element. It's not a problem in all likelihood, but following @Wrikken's advice would be wise in any case.

Comment: AH! [YES](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), sorry, I not checked... I only see the "strange &int(1)", so thanks a lot also by the `unset` alert, it resolved!

Comment: Please add as an answer that I can vote ;-)

Comment: `foreach($x as &$i) $i=1;` is **VERY** dangerous. `$i` will REMAIN a reference for the duration of your code (or until you unset it), and you can unwittingly modify the contents of the array by reusing the variable in some other context down the road.

Comment: There are no pointers in php, there are references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, this isn't technically a pointer. It is a reference. Before using them in your code, I'd suggest you get familiar with how they work in PHP by reading [the manual section that explains them](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).

In  this case, your code is actually correct, as documented in [the manual page for `foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). `foreach($x as &$i)` is precisely the way to do this. Your confusion apparently comes from the output of `var_dump`:

```
&int(1)
```

This is precisely what you should expect. The `&` signifies that another variable is a reference pointing to this value. This is because `$i` continues to be a reference to the last element in the array even after the loop is over. This is *potentially* dangerous, because code elsewhere in your file may modify `$i` and therefore your array without you wanting it to.

It is probably good practice to `unset` `$i` after the loop is over to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

When a loop ends, the iterator still holds the last value used. In this case, the last item in the array. So it's still referenced. It doesn't really matter unless you try to reuse `$i` later, in which case you may get some weird results.

It would be safer to do something like this:

```
foreach($x as $k=>$v) {
    $x[$k] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My homework affter good comments and answer at the comments.

### Read the guide

As @lonesomeday says, "that is precisely the right syntax". The [PHP guide](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) shows that

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($arr as &$value)
    $value = $value * 2;
unset($value); // break the reference with the last element
```

and, as @Wrikken say, needs the `unset`.

### Use "intermediate elegance" when you are not sure

As @MarcB20 says, take care..."`foreach($x as &$i) $i=1;` is VERY dangerous.  `$i` will REMAIN a reference for the duration of your code (or until you unset it), and you can unwittingly modify the contents of the array by reusing the variable in some other context down the road"...

So, you can use an "intermediate elegance" syntax,

```
foreach ($arr as $key=>$value) {
    // ... use $value ...
    $arr[$key] = $anothervalue;
}
```

prefer to use simple `for` (with `array_keys` if an array associative) if the $value not used.